# How to get the value of a merged cell?

Tags: c#, excel, merge, rubygems, itext

I am working on a project which has to make pdf report from couple of Excel files. The files should look like this: http://img194.imageshack.us/i/24766860.jpg/ and the pdf should look like this: http://img96.imageshack.us/i/u2ntitled.jpg/ where the location column must have the value of the merged cell in the excel file(B2:E2).

So the difficulty is how to read the merged cell and put its value in the location column.

If that info is not enough I can add the source code. If you want any other info ask I'll give it right away.

Comment: please don't forget to mark the answer if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Merged cells in excel are read by their first cell address. You should be able to pick up merged cell B2:E2 as B2